# ARCH(2) Process Stationarity

Tags: time-series, garch

Lets say that we have an ARCH(2) process such that:

1. $$ y_t = \epsilon_t \sigma_t$$ where $\epsilon_t \textit{~} MDS(0,1)$
2. $$ \sigma_t^2 = w + \alpha_1 y_{t-1}^2 + \alpha_2 y_{t-2}^2 $$

I am trying to find conditions on both $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ such that the process $y_t$ is stationary.

What I've done so far is as follows, using the iterated expectations law:

$$ VAR(y_t) = E[y_t^2] = ....E_{t-3}E_{t-2}E_{t-1} \epsilon_t^2\sigma_t^2 = ....E_{t-3}E_{t-2}E_{t-1} \epsilon_t^2[w + \alpha_1 y_{t-1}^2 + \alpha_2 y_{t-2}^2]$$

How should I proceed?